# Parent div height becomes smaller than child div height when it is floated right

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have the following html code when I have the attribute float right then the height of the parent div becomes smaller than the child's div

```
 <div id="notificationBar"> 
    <div style="float:right;">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ user }}
            <a href ="/accounts/logout/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Logout </a>
        {% else %}
            Hello Guest
            <a href ="/accounts/login/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Login </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

However when I remove th float right attribute as given below then the parent div accommodates the child div as it should normally behave.

```
<div id="notificationBar">  
    <div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ user }}
            <a href ="/accounts/logout/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Logout </a>
        {% else %}
            Hello Guest
            <a href ="/accounts/login/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Login </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Can anybody explain why is this happening. **One solution** is to set a height of the parent div, but then that is not a flexible solution. I want the height of the parent div to be changed according to the height of the child div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about clear the floating as follows

```
<div id="notificationBar">
    <div style="float:right;">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ user }}
            <a href ="/accounts/logout/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Logout </a>
        {% else %}
            Hello Guest
            <a href ="/accounts/login/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Login </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0;"></div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Why have a div at all? Why not simply set the text to align right? Float's have no inherent block height. They won't ever keep a partent div as a block if you float internal elements. You could use float: right; display: inline-block; or....

What I would do....

```
<div id="notificationBar" style="text-align: right;"> 
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello {{ user }}
        <a href ="/accounts/logout/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Logout </a>
    {% else %}
        Hello Guest
        <a href ="/accounts/login/" style="margin-left:10px;"> Login </a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

or use a paragraph rather than a div.

Of course, there maybe other factors you aren't sharing.

Answer (score 2):

add css:

```
#notificationBar { overflow:auto; }
```